# Index was outside the bounds C#

Tags: c#

i got error as: An unhandled exception of type 'System.IndexOutOfRangeException' occurred in app.exe

Additional information: Index was outside the bounds of the array.

by using code below, i appreciate your help in-advance all.

```
public string  getMissingFields(WebBrowser wb, DataRow dr)
{
    string Available2 = "";
    Available2 = wb.Document.GetElementById("ContentPlaceHolder1_reqTxt")
                  .Style.Split(';')
                  .Where(x => x.Contains("display"))
                  .ToArray()[0].Split(':')[1];

    string FieldsMissing="";
    if( Available2 .Contains( "inline" )) {
          FieldsMissing = FieldsMissing + "First name missing!" + ", ";
    }
    return FieldsMissing;
}
```

Comment: Why this question in `c` tag?

Comment: You need to debug it and check which array returns no elements. split your code and check it.

Comment: The line with Available2 = ... is just to long. Split it in parts.

Comment: Either your `ToArray()` call yields no results or your last `Split` result can't be split, either way **use the debugger**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, consider that there's no control with `id=ContentPlaceHolder1_reqTxt`:

```
var reqTxt = wb.Document.GetElementById("ContentPlaceHolder1_reqTxt");
```

You have to handle the case that it's `null`:

```
if(reqTxt != null)
{

}
```

Now consider that there's is no style `display`, then `ToArray` returns an empty array. You can use `FirstOrDefault` and check for `null` gain:

```
string Available2  = null;
if(reqTxt != null)
{
    var firstDisplayStyle = reqTxt.Split(';')
        .FirstOrDefault(s => s.Contains("display"));
    if(firstDisplayStyle != null)
    {
        string[] displaySplit = firstDisplayStyle.Split(':');
        // now handle the case that there is no colon:
        if(displaySplit.Length > 1)
            Available2 = displaySplit[1];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're assumiing that the style will always contain "display", which apparently it does not.  Replace your indexer call to offset 0 with a call to `FirstOrDefault()`, then test for null:

```
Available2 = wb.Document.GetElementById("ContentPlaceHolder1_reqTxt").Style.Split(';').Where(x   => x.Contains("display")).ToArray().FirstOrDefault();

if( null != Available2 )
{
    // continue
}
```

Comment: I would recommend also to check if `Split(':')` returns more than one item

Comment: that too.  the lesson learned here is that you need to check the length of the array before you index into it - either by `length > #` property or using `FirstOrDefault` and testing for null.

Comment: I just pointed that you should add verification of that part also.

Answer (score 1):

Two possibilities:

1. `ToArray()` returning empty array.You are trying to an element which is not exist.
2. `Split(':')` returning **zero** or **one** element.

`Debug` your code and find which one is true.

It seems you don't need `ToArray`.Just use `FirstOrDefault`, and check returning result whether null or not.If it isn't **null** call `Split` and check again to prevent exception.

```
Available2 = wb.Document.GetElementById("ContentPlaceHolder1_reqTxt")
              .Style.Split(';')
              .Where(x => x.Contains("display"))
              .FirstOrDefault();

if(Available2 != null)
{
   var text = Available2.Split(':');
   if(text.Length > 1)
   {
      var result = text[1];
   }
}
```

Comment: I think `ToArray()` should return empty array if sequence is empty. Same with Split. Also if either would return `null` we would have `NullReferenceException` instead of `IndexOutOfRange`

Comment: Also, if `null` was returned, a `NullReferenceException` would occur.

Answer (score 1):

```
Available2 = wb.Document.GetElementById("ContentPlaceHolder1_reqTxt")
              .Style.Split(';')
              .Where(x => x.Contains("display"))
              .ToArray()[0].Split(':')[1];
```

Two possible problems:

Either `ToArray()` does return an empty array, at with point accessing element `0` causes this error. Or it is at the point where you are accessing the element at index 1 - maybe there is no such element, because in the string you're trying to split there is no `:`? Debug your code or make sure that there is at least one element returned by `ToArray()` and two elements returned by `Split`.

You could try this now. This splits your code so that you can easily debug:

```
var items = wb.Document.GetElementById("ContentPlaceHolder1_reqTxt")
              .Style.Split(';')
              .Where(x => x.Contains("display"))
              .ToArray();

if (items.Count > 0)
{
    string[] split = items[0].Split(':');
    if (split.Length > 1)
        Available2 = split[1];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Available2=wb.Document.GetElementById("ContentPlaceHolder1_reqTxt").Style.Split(';').Where(x => x.Contains("display")).ToArray()[0].Split(':')[1];

To find problem, decomposite to:

```
if (wb == null || wb.Document == null )
   return;

var element = wb.Document.GetElementById("ContentPlaceHolder1_reqTxt");
if (element == null || element.Style == null)
   return;

var displayItems = element.style.Split(';').Where(x=> x.Contains("display")).FirstOrDefault();

if ( displayItems == null)
   return;

var colonItems = displayItems.Split(':');
if ( colonItems.Count() < 2 )
   return;

var Available2 = colonItems.Skip(1).First();
```